# Consulta myslqi de dos tablas con suma de registros

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli, select

Buenas haber si lo puedo explicar todo; tengo dos tablas en la BD:

`productos`

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id | producto | estado |
+----+----------+--------+
|    |          |        |
|    |          |        |
+----+----------+--------+
```

- id= numero de registro auto incrementable
- producto= nombre del producto
- estado= simplemente es si ese producto esta activo en la web, con 0 y 1.

`referencias`

```
+----+-----------+------------+---------------+
| id |idProducto | referencia | estadoMaquina | 
+----+-----------+------------+---------------+
|    |           |            |               |
|    |           |            |               |
+----+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

- id= numero de registro auto incrementable
- idProducto= esta id es la que enlaza con la id de la tabla productos, para agrupar las referancias
- referencia= la referencia de la máquina.
- estadoMaquina= Aqui decimos en que estado se encuentra esta referencia de este modo;
  0=Disponible
  1=Alquilada (ocupada)
  2=Vendida (ocupada)
  3=Exp.Compartida (ocupada)

Luego tenemos una tabla que saca y falta por sacar algunos datos.

```
 | Producto | Cantidad | Ocupadas | Disponibles | Estado |
```

**Producto** -> Sacamos el nombre.
**Cantidad** -> Sacamos gracias a un compañero cuantas maquinas hay con esa idProducto.
**Ocupadas** --> Ahí hay que sacar cuantas referencias de esa maquina están con el estadoMaquina 1,2,3.
**Disponibles** --> Aquí sacar cuantas referencias de esta maquina esta con el estadoMaquina 0.

Luego el query para sacar el ciclo while y muestre los resultados es así: (Gracias al compañero @CristianS9)

```
<?php
   //var_dump($_GET);
   $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT productos.id, productos.producto AS Producto,productos.alias AS Alias,count(idProducto) as Cantidad,estado AS Estado
   FROM referencias
   INNER JOIN productos 
   ON referencias.idProducto=productos.id
   GROUP BY idProducto,estado");                  
      mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
      while($res = $results->fetch_array()) {
?>
```

Entonces ahora estoy intentando sacar cuantas hay disponibles y lo realizo así:

```
<?php 
  $resultas = $mysqli->query("
  SELECT productos.id, productos.producto, referencias.idProducto, referencias.estadoMaquina, count(idProducto) as total
  FROM productos
  INNER JOIN referencias
  ON productos.id = referencias.idProducto AND estadoMaquina = 0        
  GROUP BY idProducto, estadoMaquina" );
    $data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultas);
    echo $data[total];
?>
```

Pero haciendolo así me saca todo el rato las disponibles de la primera id que hay 4 disponibles y me la repite en los siguientes registros. Lo bueno es que lo ejecuto dentro de PHPMyadmin y me saca bien la consulta, no se muy bien es si es porque esta consulta esta dentro de un while.

Esto son los resultado que tendría que mostrar:

```
+----------+----------+----------+-------------+--------|
| Producto | Cantidad | Ocupadas | Disponibles | Estado |
+----------+----------+----------+-------------+--------|
| Maquina1 |     5    |    1     |      4      |   1    |
| Maquina2 |     5    |    2     |      3      |   1    |
| Maquina3 |     2    |    0     |      2      |   0    |
+----------+----------+----------+-------------+--------|
```

Y esto lo que me arroja:

```
+----------+----------+----------+-------------+--------|
| Producto | Cantidad | Ocupadas | Disponibles | Estado |
+----------+----------+----------+-------------+--------|
| Maquina1 |     5    |          |      4      |   1    |
| Maquina2 |     5    |          |      4      |   1    |
| Maquina3 |     2    |          |      4      |   0    |
+----------+----------+----------+-------------+--------|
```

En ocupadas no muestra nada porque estoy haciendo el disponibles.

Alguna sugerencia, gracias!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81933/discussion-between-cristians9-and-miguel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    referencias.id,
    productos.producto,
    SUM(estadoMaquina=0) AS disponibles,
    SUM(estadoMaquina=1 || estadoMaquina=2 || estadoMaquina=3) AS ocupados,
    estado
FROM referencias
INNER JOIN productos ON idProducto=productos.id
GROUP BY idProducto
```

Puedes añadir las columnas que necesites pero la acción básica se resume a esto:
Utilizando un `GROUP BY` agruparlos por cada producto. Aprovechando esta acción hacer una suma de todas las maquinas que estén en `estadoMaquina=0` y mostrarlo como disponibles y lo mismo pero esta vez sumar el resto de estados y mostrarlos como ocupados.

Comment: @Miguel Ahora que has actualizado la pregunta es mas sencillo de entender, en si es una agrupación y un par de sumas lo que necesitabas. Creo que esta es la respuesta que buscabas. Y si todo es correcto aprovecha para eliminar los comentarios del post que ya no sean relevantes para los nuevos usuarios que puedan llegar a ver la pregunta

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, a costado hacerlo bien pero no sabia muy bien como hacerlo, la palabra SUM hace suma o que es lo que hace??

Comment: Por defecto SUM(columna) te sumara todo lo que encuentre en dicha columna, sin ambargo al indicar un valor solo sumara 1 por cada columna, Es decir te da la opcion de hacer un COUNT pero pasandole parametro

Comment: Perfecto, muchísmas gracias. E aprendido mucho estos dos días!